# How to set any file manager in Linux to show the duration like the Length feature in Windows Explorer?

Tags: sound, video, filemanager

How to set any file manager in Linux to show the duration (Length feature in Windows Explorer) of audio and video files across all folders?

Comment: I need that indication to individual files like in Windows (customizable) across ALL or at least whichever folder that contains audio and video files. If this is NOT possible, at least I should be able to do that individually/manually.

Comment: Avoid adding more information to your question in comments. Please [edit] your original question.

Comment: but it is already there. Right click on a music file in File Manager, select Properties > Audio and it gives you the duration... Same applies for Videos too.

Comment: Since readers of your question may not have access to a Windows system, please include an image of what you see using a Windows file manager.

Comment: It’s supposed to be in the status bar at the bottom in Windows: https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/52463d1265446776-status-bar-turn-off-layout1.jpg

Comment: @BSVijayAnand I got it working with Dolphin in both Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04. I'll post more information that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can have in Kubuntu 19.04 which uses Dolphin as the default file manager:

**Dolphin in Kubuntu 19.04 automatically showing the duration**

[image: Dolphin in Kubuntu 19.04 automatically showing the duration]

---

And this is how it looks in Ubuntu 18.04 running Dolphin:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 with Dolphin showing duration of videos]

---

To get Dolphin to show the duration of media files, you need to right click in the header row (containing Name, Size, Modified, etc) and then choose duration as shown in the image below:

[image: Adding a column for duration in Dolphin]

You may also need to enable *baloo*, which is a file indexer used by KDE Plasma. To do so, run `balooctl enable` from a terminal.

And if you don't want to see the preview pane on the right-hand of the file manager, use <kbd>F11</kbd> to hide/show it.

Comment: This is what I am looking for! BTB, I installed Dolphin in Ubuntu 19.04. The option is missing!

Comment: @BSVijayAnand see the edited answer. Or explain in greater detail just what isn't working.

Comment: I did as shown in the pic - Right Click'ed on the header, went to Audio>Duration and enabled/ticked it, but the Duration column is not showing anything - total blank! Both audio and video files duration is not being shown. I also ran "balooctl enable" command - it said File Indexer is already running.

Comment: Are there a lot of files? Maybe the system needs some time?

Comment: No! Even 3-4 media files' Duration is not being shown.

Comment: It works for me but not for you. In that case, please unaccept the answer. I have no further suggestions.

Comment: Same for me, duration column is blank.

Answer (score 4):

This feature already exists in a standard Ubuntu installation which includes `totem` which is installed by default.

Right click on a music or video file in File Manager ('**Files**' application or '**Nautilus**') select the *Properties* tab → *Audio* (or in the case of video, '*Audio/Video*') and it gives you the duration in minutes and seconds.

[image]

Comment: The question seems to be about folder view for files (plural).